# Sort XPath Or Operator Results

Tags: c#, xpath, or-operator

Given the following XML:

```
<xml>
    <Table>
        <Product>
            <CaseName>Test 1</CaseName>
            <Beta>banana</Beta>
            <Alpha>apple</Alpha>
            <Delta>dates</Delta>
            <Chi>chiku</Chi>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <CaseName>Test 2</CaseName>
            <Beta>borange</Beta>
            <Alpha>ared</Alpha>
            <Delta>dblue</Delta>
            <Chi>cgreen</Chi>
        </Product>
    </Table>
</xml>
```

I would like to use **XPath and the "or" operator** to dictate the order the nodes under **Product** are returned, but regardless of the XPath statement that I use, the **query results are always returned in the order of the original XML**.  For example, the following XPath statements:

1. //Delta | //CaseName | //Beta
2. //CaseName | //Beta | //Delta
3. //Delta | //Beta | //CaseName

All return nodes in the following order: CaseName, Beta, Delta, CaseName, Beta, Delta. This order matches the original XML node structure. **What XPath statement can I use with the "or" operator to return the nodes in the order that I desire?**

I'm using C# as my development environment.

Comment: Please post some code that you have written so that people can help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XPath is not a must, you can use LinqToXml to sort the elements

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //or XDocument.Load(filename)
var products = xDoc.Descendants("Product")
                .Select(p => p.Elements().OrderBy(e => e.Name.LocalName).ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Or maybe something like this

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{ "CaseName", "Beta", "Delta" };

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var products = xDoc.Descendants("Product")
                .Select(p => p.Elements()
                              .Where(e => names.Contains(e.Name.LocalName))
                              .OrderBy(e => names.IndexOf(e.Name.LocalName)).ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: XPath is not a must, so this technique will work; however, I don't see the connection between what you posted and the node names I specified when I tried to use XPath.  **Using your example, how do I use the Node Names to specify the order I want the nodes to be returned in?**

Answer (score 0):

In terms of XPath, you need to understand that XPath 1.0 only knows unordered node sets so with `//foo | //bar` you get a set of `foo` and `bar` element nodes. Most implementations then return the result in document order.

If you want to be able to define the order you need to use XPath 2.0 (or XQuery 1.0) where the data model knows ordered sequences of nodes (and atomic items), there you could use the comma operator `,` as in `//foo, //bar` to get a sequence of `foo` and `bar` element nodes. However the Microsoft .NET framework class library does not come with an XPath 2.0 implementation, you would need to use to switch to third party solutions like XmlPrime or the .NET version of Saxon 9.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinH. This is useful to know.